# How to increase size of the ViewImage/View

Tags: ios4

I am facing a problem in increasing the size of imageView/ view.

Actually I want my application to increase the size (0-100) of image/imageView after clicking a button through animation.

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a cgrect and apply that to you view/imageview

here is a code snippet

```
CGRect previousFrame = view.frame;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
previousFrame.size.width = 100;
previousFrame.size.height = 100;
view.frame = previousFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

paste this code on IBAction of your button. Change the code as you want. this is just for understanding the concept.